# What do you call those little round rubber things in door jambs?

Tags: terminology

What do you call those little round rubber things in door jambs?

Those things are used to prevent the door from hitting the jamb. It's kind of like a little round bumper.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the "official" name, but if you search online for "Cabinet Bumper", I believe you will find exactly the item you are looking for. So it could be assumed that is what they are called - you already answered your own question.
Some alternative names I saw:

- Surface Bumper
- Bumper Pad

Comment: Yep... bumper pad, or just bumper.

Answer (score 0):

They are variously called the following:

- door silencers
- cabinet door bumpers
- noise dampening bumpers